# Can a participant join multiple rooms?

Tags: livekit

I have a use case where a participant(A) need to join multiple rooms.  Lets say a participant(A) has joined a room(1) where others are participating.  Now, this participant(A) would like to join another room(2) with another group of people.  Both room 1 and 2 have unique set of participants.  The participant(A) does not want to allow the rooms to hear each other, meaning participant(A) needs to have a private conversation with room(A) or room(B) directly.  Can livekit SDKs support this workflow? Basically ParticipantA wants to join 2 separate private meetings simultaneously.